# Trying to pass data between viewcontrollers - pass annotation title to new viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have looked at all the other posts related to passing data between viewcontrollers but none of them are working for my problem.

I want to pass the title of the annotation someone taps in mapKit to a new viewcontroller so I can use that title in the new viewcontroller. I am using the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method to detect when someone has tapped the detailDisclosure button and then using the following code to add the title to the property in the second viewcontroller (called detailViewController):

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController *viewController = (detailViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailViewController"];

    detailViewController *detailView = [[detailViewController alloc] init];

    // THIS IS WHERE I SET THE ANNOTATION TITLE TO THE PROPERTY IN THE SECOND VIEWCONTROLLER
    detailView.titleTime = view.annotation.title; 

    NSLog(@"view.annotation.title: %@", view.annotation.title); // SHOWS THE TITLE
    NSLog(@"detailView.titleTime: %@", detailView.titleTime);   // SHOWS THE TITLE


    // HERE I PRESENT NEW VIEWCONTROLLER (HOPING THE TITLE IS PASSED)
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

In the second viewcontroller (detailViewController) I have this in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// set the Title Label to the titleTime (passed from the mainViewController)
self.titleForDetail.text = self.titleTime;
NSLog(@"titleForDetail.text %@:", titleForDetail.text); // THIS IS NULL
 NSLog(@"titleForDetail.text %@:", titleTime); // THIS IS NULL
}
```

Why are `self.titleForDetail.text` and `self.titleTime NULL`?  Why is nothing being passed from the original viewController?

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Yes I am using StoryBoards. But I am not using any segways....I am pushing my views programmtically.

Comment: What is titleTime? A string property? And if so, how can you refer to both self.titleTime and titleTime? In recent versions of Xcode, a property's backing instance variable is prefixed by an underscore so you know when you're using the property and when you're using the iVar. Also, what is titleForDetail? A label, UITextField or UITextView? Your code looks like titleForDetail is nil

Comment: titleForDetail is a UILAbel and titleTime is an NSString

Comment: I took away the "self" in the viewDidLoad so that it reads titleForDetail.text = titleTime; but this still doesn't work. It is as though the property titleTime is never being set or that its value is not persisting between viewcontrollers

Comment: In `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`, you are setting the property on `detailView` but then presenting `viewController`.

Comment: Anna you rock...and I feel stupid. I don't even now why I have that allocation for detailView in there...totally no needed. I just needed to set the property on viewController as that instance was already made and is the actual instance being pushed. Blah. Write it as an answer and I'll give you the check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`, the code is setting the `titleTime` property on `detailView` but then presenting `viewController` (which does not have the property set).

Change the present to:

```
[self presentViewController:detailView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It looks like you don't need the `storyboard` and `viewController` variables so you can remove them from that method.

Answer (score 1):

You have these two lines in your code:

```
    detailViewController *viewController = (detailViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailViewController"];
    detailViewController *detailView = [[detailViewController alloc] init];
```

And in the rest of the code, you sometimes use viewController, and sometimes detailView. You should only have one of those, and it should be instantiated like you do for viewController:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController *detailView = (detailViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailViewController"];
    detailView.titleTime = view.annotation.title;
    [self presentViewController:detailView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Correct...however Anna was first in the above comments. But thank you :)